# Cannot find element and get text using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: html, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to find element so that I can grab text and save it as a string using selenium webdriver however I'm getting a no such element exception.

**JAVA:**

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();              
        driver.get("https://ld2025.wdf.sap.corp/sap/bi/launchpad/#item_type=HANALYTIC");
        try{
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("got interrupted!");
        }
        WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='itemNameLbl_608963021']"));
        searchBox.click();

        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        try{
            Thread.sleep(15000);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("got interrupted!");
        }
       WebElement searchBox2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='UIComp_1']/svg/g[3]/g/g/text"));

        String number = searchBox2.getText();
        System.out.println(number);
```

HTML code link(not enough reputation to post images):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQ1F6.jpg

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more? What is exactly your question?

Comment: Just want to know how I can find the element and get the text ? Is there something wrong with my code ?

Comment: Is your control in a frame?

Comment: no, its not in the frame. Here's the whole body http://imgur.com/eeSPWz1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//text[@dominant-baseline=\"middle\"]"));
wait.until(ExpectedCondition.elementToBeClickable(element));
System.out.println(element.getText());
```

OR

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.tagName("text"));
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
{
if(list.get(i).getAttribute("x").equals("384.5"))
System.out.println(list.get(i).getText());
}
```

Comment: Still not able to find the element. Getting the same NoSuchElementException.

Comment: Get all elements by tagname, try!